# Create an IBOutlet or a UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, iboutlet

The usual method, as far as I know, of referring to an object in a nib file is creating an `IBOutlet` object and then connecting it in Interface Builder with the blue line.

But I just saw a video in Lynda.com where instead of doing that, the trainer created an `UIView` object in the header file, and connected it to his `UIView` object in Interface Builder.

So my question is: what's the benefit of using an `IBOutlet` object instead of simply using an object which is the same class of the object in IB? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IBOutlet` is just a hint to Interface Builder. IBOutlets can be anything. `UIView`, `UIButton`, `UITextView`, etc.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView * Foo;
```

In the example above, what is Foo? An IBOutlet or a UIView? It's *both*. But your question doesn't allow for that.

You might want to check out the Apple documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/06Controller/06Controller.html

Where they further describe the role of IBOutlet:

> An object can communicate with other
>   objects in an application by sending
>   messages to outlets. An outlet can
>   reference any object in an
>   application: user interface objects
>   such as text fields and buttons, model
>   objects (usually instances of custom
>   classes), and even the application
>   object itself. Outlets are special
>   instance variables because they can be
>   set in Interface Builder.

And:

> Note: IBOutlet is a null-defined macro
>   that the C preprocessor removes at
>   compile time. Interface Builder uses
>   it to identify outlet declarations so
>   that it can display them when
>   connecting outlets visually.

In summary:

IBOutlets can reference pretty much anything. They are just a hint to Interface Builder which lets you set their value when you load the XIB. In fact, the text `IBOutlet` means so little outside of the Interface Builder world, that it gets stripped from the final product because it's completely non-functional for any purpose other than helping out Interface Builder.

I'd go back and check out some of the other things you were hooking up as `IBOutlets`, and you'll surely discover they actually do have some real type.

Comment: if we are creating IBOutlets how and when the memory is allocated?

Answer (score 2):

IBOutlet is just a keyword to indicate to IB, "Hey, this should be an outlet!" It's not really an object type — it's literally erased by the preprocessor. If you specify that the outlet is of type UIVIew, though, IB will ensure that it can only be hooked up to UIView-type things.